# How to get projected angle from quaternion on a certain axis?

Tags: c#, graphics, quaternions

I am using quaternions in my game to calculate some basic angles.

Now I am trying to get the angle of a quaternion, given a certain axis. So, given a quaternion and a new axis. Can I get the projected angle back?

To me, it seems like a solid way to calculate the signed angle between two vectors. The code is written in Unity3D C#, but this does not necessarily has to be the case. It's more of a general method.

```
public static float DirectionalAngle(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Vector3 up)
{
    // project the vectors on the plane with up as a normal
    Vector3 f = Vector3.Exclude(up, from);
    Vector3 t = Vector3.Exclude(up, to);

    // creates an angle-axis rotation
    Quaternion q = Quaternion.FromToRotation(f, t);

    // do something to get the angle out of the quaternion,
    // given the new axis.
    // TODO: Make this method. Doesn't exist.
    Quaternion q2 = Quaternion.GetAngleFromAxis(q, Vector3.right);

    return q2.Angle(q2);
}
```

I can always get the angle and axis from the quaternion, as well as x,y,z,w and the euler angles. But I don't see a way to get the projected angle from the quaternion on the axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! The only thing I had to do was rotate the quaternion in such a way that it is oriented in the local space. The method seems to be sound for all planes I've tested it on.

```
public static float DirectionalAngle(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Vector3 up)
{
    // project the vectors on the plane with up as a normal
    Vector3 f = Vector3.Exclude(up, from);
    Vector3 t = Vector3.Exclude(up, to);

    // rotate the vectors into y-up coordinates
    Quaternion toZ = Quaternion.FromToRotation(up, Vector3.up);
    f = toZ * f;
    t = toZ * t;

    // calculate the quaternion in between f and t.
    Quaternion fromTo = Quaternion.FromToRotation(f,t);

    // return the eulers.
    return fromTo.eulerAngles.y;
}
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly; Aren't you looking for the angle between the projected vectors `f` and `t`? In that case, this should be enough: `Vector3.Angle(f, t)`

Comment: No that will give me the unsigned angle. I need the signed (directional) angle of the two. So really, *from* to *to*. But I don't like the `atan2` approaches that are commonly used.

Comment: The `atan2` method is really the way to go. This is terribly inefficient (and still includes an atan2 under the hood anyway).